# Using the results of a MongoDB db.collection.aggregate to exclude results from a db.collection.find

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am programming a MongoDB function in AngularJS and Node and I have a single collection that has a field called documentId that is not unique.  I want to find all docs in that collection where NONE of the status fields of a particular document contains the word open and only include the documents where ALL of the status' are either "closed" or "canceled".

Ex:

`_id: <val> , companyId : "CO-000001", documentId : "001", status:"closed", value:"123.45"
_id: <val> , companyId : "CO-000001", documentId : "002", status:"closed", value:"323.67"
_id: <val> , companyId : "CO-000001", documentId : "001", status:"open", value:"434.56"
_id: <val> , companyId : "CO-000001", documentId : "002", status:"canceled", value:"523.16"`

I want my results to ONLY include documentId 002 and not documentId 001 because one of the documents with documentId 001 contains a status of open.  But since all documents with documentId 002 have a status of closed or canceled, I want to include it in my result.

I can get the aggregate of what documents I want to exclude from a db.collection.find() using the following...

```
db.tickets.aggregate(
[
    { 
        "$match" : {
            "companyId" : "CO-000001", 
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "status" : {
                        "$in" : [
                            "open","on hold" 
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : null, 
            "uniqueValues" : {
                "$addToSet" : "$documentId"
            }
        }
    }
], 
{ 
    "allowDiskUse" : false
}
```

);

but now I want to use the array results from the aggregate in a query when doing my...

```
db.tickets.find("companyId":"CO-000001", $and:[{documentId:{$nin:[<results from aggregation>]}}])
```

Is there a way to use the results from the aggregation inside another query?  or is there a way to do all of this within an aggregation?

Comment: use $lookup in the aggregate itself to join the table and get results.

Comment: $lookup would INCLUDE the docs from the result.  I want to exclude them.

Comment: Just project whatever you want

Comment: I dont think you are taking the time to understand the problem.  Projecting allows you to specify what fields you want returned.  Im not looking to exclude fields, but rather exclude entire documents.  I am getting the impression that you do not understand the problem set.

Answer (score 0):

Change the projections according to your need. observe how I used group and match stage later to get the required data. Hope this solves your problem.

```
 db.tickets.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "companyId" : "CO-000001"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$documentId", 
                "status" :{
                "$addToSet" : "$status"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $match:{ status:{$nin:["open","on hold"]} }
        },{
        $lookup:{  
             from:"tickets",
             as: "final",
             localField: "_id",
             foreignField: "documentId",
          }
        },
        {
            $project :{
                _id:0,
                final:1
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
    ).pretty();
```

Comment: This is great!  Thank you so much.  I only had to make one tweak... I had to first do a group by uniqueValues before the lookup.  But other than that this gave me precisely what I needed.  Maybe I didnt understand what you were saying in the comments above, but with the example it made it clear.

Comment: Can I know what is the tweak you made?

Comment: Just adding group by unique values prior to the lookup.

Comment: bit confused though, Hope my answer solved your problem.

Comment: When I did the lookup with just your solution, it came back with multiple entries per document.  I just needed one, so by grouping by uniqueValues on documentId prior to doing the lookup, I got just one document result per documentId that matched the criteria.